# How to group CSV lines by multiple column

Tags: awk, files, sort, csv

I am working on a file that contains the following format:

```
R      |  CF    |  PN    |  seq          |  UC  

801    |  10    |  P3    |  643455423    |  C1    
804    |  11    |  P1    |  643455427    |  C1    
804    |  11    |  P1    |  643455427    |  C5    
802    |  11    |  P2    |  643455431    |  C1    
800    |  11    |  P2    |  643455429    |  C2    
800    |  11    |  P2    |  643455429    |  C2    
802    |  11    |  P2    |  643455431    |  C2    
800    |  11    |  P3    |  643455423    |  C1    
804    |  11    |  P3    |  643455433    |  C2    
802    |  11    |  P3    |  643455425    |  C3    
804    |  11    |  P3    |  643455433    |  C3    
802    |  11    |  P4    |  643455425    |  C2    
801    |  12    |  P1    |  643455424    |  C2    
801    |  12    |  P1    |  643455424    |  C2    
805    |  12    |  P1    |  643455434    |  C2    
805    |  12    |  P1    |  643455434    |  C3    
805    |  12    |  P3    |  643455428    |  C1    
805    |  12    |  P3    |  643455428    |  C1    
801    |  12    |  P3    |  643455430    |  C3    
803    |  14    |  P1    |  643455432    |  C1    
803    |  14    |  P1    |  643455432    |  C1    
803    |  14    |  P2    |  643455426    |  C1    
803    |  14    |  P2    |  643455426    |  C3    
801    |  19    |  P4    |  643455430    |  C3
```

I am trying to group lines by the most ressemblece (Greatest-Common-Divisor like) by those three columns.
That means if two lines or more share the same CF-PN-UC values, they should be grouped, if not so, those who shares the same CF-PN should be grouped, but if not, the rest must be grouped by the CF.

Is there a way that i can get the following as result?

```
R      |  CF    |  PN    |  seq          |  UC  
#CF
801    |  10    |  P3    |  643455423    |  C1  
#CF-PN
804    |  11    |  P1    |  643455427    |  C1    
804    |  11    |  P1    |  643455427    |  C5       
#CF-PN-UC
800    |  11    |  P2    |  643455429    |  C2    
800    |  11    |  P2    |  643455429    |  C2    
802    |  11    |  P2    |  643455431    |  C2    
#CF-PN
800    |  11    |  P3    |  643455423    |  C1    
804    |  11    |  P3    |  643455433    |  C2    
#CF-PN-UC
802    |  11    |  P3    |  643455425    |  C3    
804    |  11    |  P3    |  643455433    |  C3  
#CF
802    |  11    |  P2    |  643455431    |  C1  
802    |  11    |  P4    |  643455425    |  C2    
#CF-PN-UC
801    |  12    |  P1    |  643455424    |  C2    
801    |  12    |  P1    |  643455424    |  C2    
805    |  12    |  P1    |  643455434    |  C2    
#CF-PN-UC
805    |  12    |  P3    |  643455428    |  C1    
805    |  12    |  P3    |  643455428    |  C1  
#CF
805    |  12    |  P1    |  643455434    |  C3 
801    |  12    |  P3    |  643455430    |  C3    
#CF-PN-UC
803    |  14    |  P1    |  643455432    |  C1    
803    |  14    |  P1    |  643455432    |  C1    
#CF-PN
803    |  14    |  P2    |  643455426    |  C1    
803    |  14    |  P2    |  643455426    |  C3    
#CF
801    |  19    |  P4    |  643455430    |  C3
```

Thanks for Your Help.

Comment: suggest to reduce sample size, like less than 10 lines... look into https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a sorting problem:

```
head -2 input.file; tail -n +3 input.file | sort -t '|' -k2,2n -k3,3 -k5,5
```

That means: "Sort by column 2 numerically. In the case of a tie, sort by column 3. In the case of a tie, sort by column 5.